# Having trouble switching a mat-icon back & forth between two icons

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I know I need to do a for loop or an if-statement of some sort, I've just been trying to put the pieces together for a few hours now with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html

```
<button  type="button" mat-icon-button mat-mini-fab data-bs-target="#sidebar" 
          data-bs-toggle="collapse" (click)="changeIcon('arrow_back')"
          color="primary"><mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon></button> <!--arrow_back-->
```

ts component

```
public icon = 'arrow_forward';
public changeIcon(newIcon: string){
this.icon = newIcon;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to toggle between the two icons, you can do something like this:

```
<button type="button" mat-icon-button mat-mini-fab data-bs-target="#sidebar" 
        data-bs-toggle="collapse" (click)="changeIcon()"
        color="primary"><mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon></button>
```

```
public icon = 'arrow_forward';
public changeIcon(): void {
   this.icon = this.icon === 'arrow_forward' ? 'arrow_back' : 'arrow_forward';
}
```

Comment: Oh my bad, forgot the parenthesis in the HTML code for the changeIcon method. So it should be `(click)="changeIcon()"`. Here's a working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-m2bmpf?file=app/app.component.html

Also just updated the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, it switches to arrow_back when you click on it. If you want to switch back to arrow_forward on the click it again you can simply toggle the values

```html
<button type="button" mat-icon-button mat-mini-fab data-bs-target="#sidebar" 
              data-bs-toggle="collapse" (click)="changeIcon()"
              color="primary">
              <mat-icon> {{icon}} </mat-icon>
</button>
```

```js
 icon:string = 'arrow_forward';
 public changeIcon(): string {
    const temp = this.icon === 'arrow_forward'? 'arrow_back' : 'arrow_forward'
    this.icon = temp;
 }
```